# Facebook SDK login button hangs on Facebook activity when uninstalling app and reinstalling

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-3.1

I am using the `Facebook SDK 3.19` for my app and have a recurring bug. I am using the `com.facebook.widget.LoginButton` to control my login flow.

Anytime I uninstall my app and reinstall, the login button "breaks" and changes to the `Facebook activity` but gets stuck and just shows an empty screen. It does not direct it back to my app's activity as it should. It keeps doing this no matter if I try to close the app, force close the app, etc. Same hanging every time.

But if I uninstall the `Facebook app` and use the Web Dialog for login, it works no problem. Or if I uninstall and reinstall the `Facebook app` it will work with no issues. The trigger for this bug is when I uninstall my app and reinstall.

**Has anyone ever experienced this problem? And if so, is there a way around this bug?**